# Javascript string construction by concatenation?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, construction

Exploring Javascript (and coming from the Java world). I have the following line of code in a script:

```
if (jQuery) {  
    document.getElementById("BOTTOM_MID").innerHTML
        = "JQuery Loaded - " + getTime();
}
```

but it does not work. `BOTTOM_MID` is not initialized. Yet, the following works:

```
if (jQuery) {  
    document.getElementById("BOTTOM_MID").innerHTML
        = "JQuery Loaded";
}
```

Doesn't Javascript understand string construction by concatenation? If yes, how should I proceed?

Comment: is `getTime` defined elsewhere? it's not a javascript default function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTime()` is a method of the `Date` object. Try this:

```
if (jQuery) {  
    document.getElementById("BOTTOM_MID").innerHTML
        = "JQuery Loaded - " +  new Date().getTime();
}
```

Since you're using jQuery, I also suggest that you use jQuery's `ready()` handler and selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#BOTTOM_MID").html("JQuery Loaded - " +  new Date().getTime());
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/aWYf3/).

Comment: A slightly more abbreviated way would be `(+new Date)`.

Comment: True; I was just mentioning it.

Comment: @icktoofay [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) FTW

Comment: Date.now() isn't supported in IE (maybe IE9, but definitely not earlier versions)

Comment: `Date.now = Date.now || function() { return +new Date; };`

Comment: @icktoofay This would be more proper: `if ( !Date.now ) { Date.now = function () { ... }; }`. You only want to make that assignment if it's really necessary. (There is no reason to execute `Date.now = Date.now` in browsers that implement it...)

Comment: Thanks, new Date() solved the issue, I was already using $(document).ready(...).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, try to run this on your chrome developer tools or firebug's console, in this web page:

```
 document.getElementById("notify-container").innerHTML = "JQuery Loaded - " + "hello"
```

It will work, indeed.

Perhaps you don't have `getTime()` defined? It's not a standard javascript function BTW